# In chrome third party url gets encrypted with % symbol making it invalid at run time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, encryption

[Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh9f0.jpg)[Code.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g75cQ.jpg)
[url.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbIMz.jpg)In my code I am trying to go navigate to a third party website using Response.redirect.

It's working fine in Internet explorer.
But In chrome some percentage symbols are coming due to which it throws error during login as 'Uncaught TypeError: .. is not a valid url'

Please suggest

Comment: URLs should be percent encoded, please show your code creating the URL.

Comment: Yes you are right urls get default encoded.Not sure why same url is working in IE but not in chrome.PFA for details. Where url.png is the final url,code.png is the code part through which it navigates to third party url,error.png is error thrown in chrome as seen through F12

Comment: POST actual code, not images of code.